# Understanding FeathersJS hooks

Tags: feathersjs

I'm following [the tutorial](http://docs.feathersjs.com/hooks/usage.html). In `Asynchronous hooks`, there's a snippet like this:

```
todoService.before({
  find(hook) {
    return this.find().then(data => {
      hook.params.message = 'Ran through promise hook';
      hook.data.result = data;
      // Always return the hook object
      return hook;
    });
  }
});
```

Would you please let me know what `this.find()` is supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` is a [Feathers service method](http://docs.feathersjs.com/services/readme.html#service-methods) and `this` is [the service the hook is running on](http://docs.feathersjs.com/hooks/usage.html#after-hooks).

Comment: So the flow will be:
1. The hook will call the service to modify associated data
2. The service is invoked on the modified data
Is that right?

Comment: Ah, I see the problem, `hook.data.result = data;` is not very useful here. I took it out of the documentation. Basically it calls the services `find` method. Then you can do something with that data and e.g. add some information with `hook.params.message` which will then be available in the following hooks and the service method call `params`. `before` hooks let you modify the query, parameters and user submitted data (e.g. validation) where `after` hooks let you modify the returned data.

Comment: Well, I think we should have a `better demo` here! Instead of letting `find hook` calls `find service` (and then `find service` is executed once again), we should do things like: `hook.app.service('messages').find().then()`. I think it's much clearer to understand the code.

Comment: Makes sense. You are welcome to [change it here](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-docs/edit/master/hooks/usage.md)